# Can I use Slack events API with slash commands?

Tags: python, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I want to use [slash commands](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/slash-commands) in Slack to integrate with an external API. In the API I need to [verify a request](https://api.slack.com/authentication/verifying-requests-from-slack) from Slack. The docs [suggest](https://api.slack.com/authentication/verifying-requests-from-slack#sdk_support) that I should use the [Python Events API SDK](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slack-events-api) for that. Can anyone explain how exactly I should use that API? Can I listen for a particular event corresponding to slash commands, or should I somehow reuse the request verification code from that API?

Answer (score 0):

The docs suggest that you should aim to re-use an existing library that handles the signed secret verification, rather than writing your own code to do it, it possible.

But if none of the suggested libraries work you, I would suggest to rather write that code yourself then introducing a large library with 99% functions that you do not need. Especially since the algorithm is not that complex.

And no, Events and Slack commands are different concepts. So there is not slash command event to listen for.